# How to append data one by one in existing file in android?

Tags: android, file-io, java-io

How to append data one by one in existing file? Am using following code.. Append the data row order in file..How to solve this?

```
    private String SaveText() {

    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"GPS");
    dir.mkdirs();

    String fname =  "gps.txt";
    File file = new File (dir, fname);

   FileOutputStream fos;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
        OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        out.write(value1);
        out.close();
        fos.close();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved lat,long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return dir.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: If you are using java 7 you can try `Files.write...()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    try{

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file,true), "UTF-8");
        BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        fbw.write(value1);
        fbw.newLine();
        fbw.close();
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved lat,long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Am using your code work fine but same value stored one by one that is why?

Comment: fbw.newLine(); so that stored one by one

Comment: if you satisfied answer, click +1 for post

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code.

```
public void SaveText(String sFileName, String sBody){
try
{
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Notes");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
    writer.append(sBody);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
     importError = e.getMessage();
     iError();
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

In **JAVA 7**  you can try:

```
       try {

             Files.write(Paths.get(dir+File.separator+fname), latLng.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

checkout Beautiful explanation :[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Comment: Android is Java 6 based and there is no backport of `java.nio.file`